# Is it possible rename fields in the outputs of a Mongo query in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have some documents in Mongo:

```
{"name" : "John", "age" : 26}
{"name" : "Paul", "age" : 34}
{"name" : "George", "age" : 36}
```

and another function that expects documents of the form:

```
{"name" : "XXX", "value" : YY}
```

Is it possible to rename the 'age' field to 'value' in a find query in PyMongo?

Comment: I know it's not what has been asked, but why do it in MongoDB-dependent way when you can rename the field after querying MongoDB through simple Python code? You can even preserve iterator semantic my using generator expression:

    return ({"name": doc["name"], "value": doc["age"]} for doc in collection.find()})

Comment: @MichaelKorbakov I would suggest the reason is for speed. Mongo is likely going to be faster at renaming fields in the data

Answer (score 19):

I'd use the `aggregate` method with `$project` operator.

From mongodb web docs.

> You may also use $project to rename fields. Consider the following
>   example:

```
db.article.aggregate(
 { $project : {
     title : 1 ,
     page_views : "$pageViews" ,
     bar : "$other.foo"
 }} );`
```

e.g.

```
db.mycol.aggregate({ $project : { name:1, value:"$age" }});
```

see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_project

Comment: find(), also has the projection method, but I found it doesn't support rename