# Transform mongodb documents and subdocuments to replace _id with id in a recursive loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, recursion, mongoose

I have a typical mongoose schematic collection like this:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "name" : "CIMA",
    "_id" : ObjectId("563ff96bb61f6b2c0e82f93e"),
    "subjects" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 1 */
{
    "name" : "TESTDDD",
    "_id" : ObjectId("563ffa1db61f6b2c0e82f940"),
    "subjects" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "name" : "testing new thing",
    "_id" : ObjectId("564cbc605adf343c0dc49e95"),
    "subjects" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "name" : "asdfsdf",
    "_id" : ObjectId("564cc0f45adf343c0dc49e96"),
    "subjects" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "name" : "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsd",
    "_id" : ObjectId("564ced6ed68ef5d00d5ad4db"),
    "subjects" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("563ff5de8e3ae0ce0d5f65a7"),
    "name" : "TEST EDITED",
    "subjects" : []
}

/* 6 */
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("563566b572b65918095f1db3"),
    "name" : "TEST COURSE",
    "subjects" : []
}

/* 7 */
{
    "name" : "sub one",
    "_id" : ObjectId("564d017d4e13a8640e6b1738"),
    "subjects" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("563febb75a9909ae0d25d025"),
    "name" : "testing course",
    "subjects" : []
}

/* 9 */
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("563ff95ab61f6b2c0e82f93d"),
    "name" : "324234",
    "subjects" : []
}

/* 10 */
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("563ff8d2b61f6b2c0e82f93b"),
    "name" : "asdfasfd",
    "subjects" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "some suject",
            "_id" : ObjectId("564d05842582c8fe0eb4362d"),
            "topics" : []
        }
    ]
}

/* 11 */
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("563ff8fbb61f6b2c0e82f93c"),
    "name" : "asfdasfasfd",
    "subjects" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsd",
            "_id" : ObjectId("564d05c82582c8fe0eb4362e"),
            "topics" : []
        }
    ]
}

/* 12 */
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("563ff735b61f6b2c0e82f938"),
    "name" : "test",
    "subjects" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("564d04e32582c8fe0eb4362b"),
            "name" : "test subject",
            "topics" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "test subject edite",
            "_id" : ObjectId("564d46a4adcf28580f631eca"),
            "topics" : []
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("564d46b4adcf28580f631ecb"),
            "name" : "test subject edited",
            "topics" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "test subject edite again",
            "_id" : ObjectId("564d4759d6fe04640f99701a"),
            "topics" : []
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("564d4793ef24f5670f62ba22"),
            "name" : "test subject yet again",
            "topics" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "test subject edited TWO TIMES",
            "_id" : ObjectId("564d4989ef24f5670f62ba23"),
            "topics" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i need the client to receive this with all the _id replaced with id no matter at what level the document is in the nested structure. So I wrote a transformation recursive function like this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = {
    toClient: transformCollection
}

function transformCollection(theObject) {
var result = null, object = {};

if(theObject instanceof Array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {
        theObject[i] = process.nextTick(function () {transformCollection(theObject[prop]);}); // <----Assignment
    }
}
else
{
    for (var prop in theObject) {
        if (prop == '_id') {
            theObject.id = theObject._id; // <----Typo
            delete theObject._id;
            delete theObject.__v;
        }
        else if (theObject[prop] instanceof Array) {
            theObject[prop] = process.nextTick(function () {transformCollection(theObject[prop]);}); // <----Assignment
        }
    }
}
return theObject;
   }
```

And called as:

```
  courseModel.find(function(err,courses){
            if(err){
                res.json(error.dbRetrievalError);
            }
            else
            {
                res.json(utils.toClient(courses));
            }
        })
```

So a couple of questions here:

1. Is it the right way to achieve this?
2. If yes, then can anyone point my recursive function in the right direction? I 
   am getting a Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Comment: possibly related? (if this fixes the problem, then... the answer to #1 is a definitive **No**) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463087/is-it-possible-rename-fields-in-the-outputs-of-a-mongo-query-in-pymongo

Comment: Care to give some pointers with mongoose or why this would create a problem?

Comment: the aggregate method also exists within mongoose. If it can be done with mongodb directly, chances are you can do it with mongoose too.

Comment: Here's another way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034848/mongodb-output-id-instead-of-id though i'd avoid that method, i wouldn't want to blanket force all routes to replace _id with id. I'd prefer something more... case by case.

Comment: Problem with all these is that they do not deal with nested subdocuments. That's where I am stuck!

Comment: Why are you doing this? `theObject[prop] = process.nextTick` in particular, the `theObject[prop] =` part.

Comment: to go loop through the subset

Comment: Ah, gotcha, yea that won't work. you'll need to pass that into the function somehow, and have the function modify it rather than return something. The return becomes rather useless when using process.nextTick()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95749/discussion-between-benerd-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a couple of assignments from the result of your recursion. There is also a typo in your for-in where you set `object.id` instead of `theObject.id`.

Does this work?

```
function transformCollection(theObject) {
    var result = null, object = {};

    if(theObject instanceof Array) {
        for(var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {
            theObject[i] = transformCollection(theObject[i]); // <----Assignment
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (var prop in theObject) {
            if (prop == '_id') {
                theObject.id = theObject._id; // <----Typo
                delete theObject._id;
            }
            else if (theObject[prop] instanceof Array) {
                theObject[prop] = transformCollection(theObject[prop]); // <----Assignment
            }
        }
    }
    return theObject;
}
```

Comment: to fix the call stack exceeded, you'd need to push calls to transformCollection to the next tick. `process.nextTick(function () {transformCollection(theObject[prop]);});`

Comment: Combining @KevinB and i get a array with all properties mapped to null. Doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and wrote this recursive function that does the job:

```
function cleanupId(doc, ret) {
  if (ret.hasOwnProperty('_id')) {
    ret.id = doc._id;
    delete ret._id;
  }
  
  for (let prop in doc) {
    if (Array.isArray(ret[prop])) {
      doc[prop].forEach((elem, index) => {
        cleanupId(doc[prop][index], ret[prop][index]);
      });
    }
  }
}
```