# Removing duplicate keys after $unwind in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Using MongoDB, I'm doing an aggregation pipeline on a document that contains an array called `tests`, and using an `$unwind` operation to unwind that array into several documents:

Original document:

```
{"_id"=>"1867930", "tests"=> [
    {"status"=>"passed", "elapsed_time"=>26, "worker"=>11},
    {"status"=>"passed", "elapsed_time"=>34, "worker"=>13},
    {"status"=>"passed", "elapsed_time"=>23, "worker"=>15}
]}
```

Result after `$unwind`:

```
{"_id"=>"1867930", "tests"=>{"status"=>"passed", "elapsed_time"=>26, "worker"=>11}}
{"_id"=>"1867930", "tests"=>{"status"=>"passed", "elapsed_time"=>34, "worker"=>13}}
{"_id"=>"1867930", "tests"=>{"status"=>"passed", "elapsed_time"=>23, "worker"=>15}}
```

How can I apply another operation to hoist the values of the `tests` key in each of these documents up a level (i.e. eliminating the duplicate `tests` keys created from the `$unwind`) to get the following result?

```
{"_id"=>"1867930", "status"=>"passed", "elapsed_time"=>26, "worker"=>11}
{"_id"=>"1867930", "status"=>"passed", "elapsed_time"=>34, "worker"=>13}
{"_id"=>"1867930", "status"=>"passed", "elapsed_time"=>23, "worker"=>15}
```

Note that this is *not* renaming the `tests` key, it's moving the value of `tests` up a level and merging with the parent hash.

Comment: Duplicates? What does this have to do with duplicates? Surely all you are asking is how to make `"tests.status"` etc into just `"status`". That is what you are asking right? Just renaming keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible rename fields in the outputs of a Mongo query in PyMongo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463087/is-it-possible-rename-fields-in-the-outputs-of-a-mongo-query-in-pymongo)

Comment: @BlakesSeven no, this is not renaming, it's moving the value of `tests` and merging it into the parent.

Comment: Yes it is renaming. Just as the answer on the linked duplicate does, and just as the answer added here that is a copy of that response does. That is the way you do it. With JavaScript manipulation of mapReduce you could do something more generic such as adding to the parent. But your question like the other is about the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it through [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$tests'}, 
  {$project: 
     {status: '$tests.status', 
      elapsed_time: '$tests.elapse_time',
      worker: '$tests.worker'}}
]);
```

Or do it as following with cursor `forEach` to print the data format

```
db.collection.find({ "tests": {"$exists": 1 }}).forEach(
   function(doc){
      for (var i in doc.tests){
         doc.tests[i]._id = doc._id; 
         printjson(doc.tests[i]);
      }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work but is there a more general way to do it without having to project every single key? The real data (not shown in the question) has quite a few keys in the `tests` hash.

Comment: @KenLiu, maybe you could try to do it with `cursor forEach` as it shown in my answer.