# Why does renaming a field in a child array of objects in mongodb returning an array when using $project in aggregate function?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

My query goes like this im using aggregate function with lookup:

```
this.document.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup : {
      from: "projects",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "organization_id",
      as: "projects",
    }, 
  },
  {
    $lookup : {
      from: "accounts",
      localField: "accounts",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "organization_accounts",
    },
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id" : false,
      "id": "$_id",
      "name": 1,
      "email": "$email",
      "projects.id": "$projects._id",
      "projects.name" : 1,
      "projects.organization_id" : 1,
      "organization_accounts._id" : 1,
      "organization_accounts.first_name" : 1,
      "organization_accounts.last_name" : 1,
      "organization_accounts.email" : 1,
      "organization_accounts.main_org_id" : 1,
    }
  }
])
```

But the output goes like this:

```
  "id": "5ec69acbc072871bb03dd773",
  "email": "organization email",
  "name": "Organization name",
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "project 1",
      "organization_id": "5ec69acbc072871bb03dd773",
      "id": [
        "5ec6a08342ad5b0a28ba6876"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "organization_accounts": []
```

I've tried applying the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463087/is-it-possible-rename-fields-in-the-outputs-of-a-mongo-query-in-pymongo)  but it doesnt seem to work or idk.

The projects.id field should be a string not an array.

P.S: Just new to mongoDB

Comment: what is this : ***qweqweqweqweqw asdasdasdasd asd asd asd asd as dasd asd asd as dasd asd as dasdasd as das das dasd as das d as das d asd as das das*** in your question ? edit your question..

Comment: It's because `projects` is an array ! Do you always have only one object in `projects` array or can be multiple ?

Comment: @whoami its an array of objects, it's always multiple.

Comment: then you can't do that, you need to unwind it..

Answer (score 1):

You have to $unwind the embedded arrays. You will get the cartesian product of array length for each document. [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V5Pk2pcZbcH)

```
this.document.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup : {
      from: "projects",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "organization_id",
      as: "projects",
    }, 
  },
  {
    $lookup : {
      from: "accounts",
      localField: "accounts",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "organization_accounts",
    },
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id" : false,
      "id": "$_id",
      "name": 1,
      "email": "$email",
      "projects.id": "$projects._id",
      "projects.name" : 1,
      "projects.organization_id" : 1,
      "organization_accounts._id" : 1,
      "organization_accounts.first_name" : 1,
      "organization_accounts.last_name" : 1,
      "organization_accounts.email" : 1,
      "organization_accounts.main_org_id" : 1,
    }
  },
   {
    $unwind: "$projects"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$projects.id"
  }
])
```